# How to set default print option in browser

Tags: html, css, printing

I am setting up a friendly printable document for my client. From that, I would like to set a default print option to have a page footer for page number option selected by default.
It is like this:

[image]

So far, I know there is an option like:

```
@page {
  size: auto; 
  margin: 0mm;  
}
```

However, I am not quite sure it is possible have above option selected or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to make it so **Headers and footers** is selected in Chrome by default, or are you asking how to target print?

Comment: @MatthewBeckman, sorry making confused. I would like have to option `Header and footers` selected by default. That meant my user will not have to select it very time they want to print. This will include `header and footers` for them already when they print out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the default settings for browsers like that. '**Headers and footers**' is a user option in Chrome. Chrome is going to respect the users preferences, not the websites.

The [`@page`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) rule you're trying to use is only able to hide the headers and footers because you're able to change the margins, but it's not really what it was designed for.

With that said, you can still choose to make your own headers and footers that are only visible when printing. For example:

## HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="print-head">Page 1. Hidden in browser, shows up printing.</div>
  <div>This is just a normal div that shows up on both.</div>
</body>
```

## CSS

```
#print-head {
  display: none;
}
@media print {
  #print-head {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I know you said you wanted pages numbers, but you'd need to know exactly where the page breaks were going to happen. Even if you defined the page breaks yourself, there is no guarantee that users settings / environments won't introduce additional breaks, which would put the headers / footers out of place.

Comment: thanks, and sound great. As you mentioned, the page number was the only problem I am facing and try to achieved. Having searching through solution, I tried using this decorator `@bottom-right` yet sadly it is not supported. :(